# Mouse pointer speed keep resetting while running

Tags: windows-vista, mouse

The problem I am facing from quite some time now is that my mouse pointer keeps  resetting to maximum speed often while the system is still running.

I am using updated AVG 2012 antivirus and the system scan shows no traces of any virus. My operating system is windows vista ultimate and I am not using setpoint for controlling my mouse.

Please suggest me how to solve this problem.